# How do I check table level policies (e.g. cache) for all tables in a given database?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

How do I check table level policies (e.g. cache) for all tables in a given database with a single command?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out, so posting as an answer:-

```
.show table * policy caching
```

Answer (score 1):

in many cases, looking at the *effective* policies for tables is more useful than the table-level policies which are defined, as doing the latter won't take into account the database-level policy (if it is defined)

for seeing the effective policies, you can use `.show tables details`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/tables#show-table-details